# Google Document List API 308 Resume Incomplete

Tags: php, rest, google-api

I am working with the Google Document List API to upload a file along with meta-data.

I have it working perfectly so long as the file is less than 512KB. After 512KB I have to send it in 512KB chunks. After each chunk I get a HTTP Status Code of 308 sent back, which is correct.

However, after I have sent the final request I still get a 308 response, instead of the 201 response I expect. Below are the HTTP Headers sent and received. Maybe someone else can see what I am missing.

```
POST /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer <CODE>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
X-Upload-Content-Length: 1436480
X-Upload-Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Length: 302

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 5 2012 17:14:59 (1346890499)
Location: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?upload_id=<ID>
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 17:34:50 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

PUT /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?upload_id=<ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer <CODE>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Range: bytes 0-524288/1436480
Content-Length: 524288
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 5 2012 17:14:59 (1346890499)
Range: bytes=0-524287
X-Range-MD5: 8f470cff00adda7c22b8b34287d2cc1b
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 17:34:52 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

PUT /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?upload_id=<ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer <CODE>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Range: bytes 524288-1048576/1436480
Content-Length: 524288
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 5 2012 17:14:59 (1346890499)
Range: bytes=0-1048575
X-Range-MD5: 4af215a3ff92258bb1c8d05dc52cf77d
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 17:34:54 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

PUT /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?upload_id=<ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer <CODE>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Length: 387904
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 5 2012 17:14:59 (1346890499)
Range: bytes=0-1048575
X-Range-MD5: 4af215a3ff92258bb1c8d05dc52cf77d
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 17:34:55 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**EDIT**

Here are the last Headers if I make the Content Range be sent on the last PUT request.

```
PUT /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?upload_id=<ID< HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer <CODE>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Range: bytes 1048576-1436480/1436480
Content-Length: 387904
Expect: 100-continue

Got
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 5 2012 17:14:59 (1346890499)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 19:12:06 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 15
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your last request is not sending a `Content-Range`. I think this is the problem but am unsure because I have never used this API before. I'm just going off what I know in the HTTP spec.

Comment: I added the Content Range to the last request and it caused a 400 error.

Comment: You were correct about the Content-Range. The 400 errors with a red haring.